# Copy / Paste format using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to copy / paste format from once column to another using `gspread`. My sheet looks like this:

[image]

My result should look like this:

[image]

I tried:

But for some reason this does not copy the format and I am not sure where is my mistake.

```
GSHEETS_SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
]



CLIENT_SECRET_GOOGLE_SHEETS = r"folder/file.json"
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET_GOOGLE_SHEETS, GSHEETS_SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("My Sheet")

body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "copyPaste": {
                "source": {
                    "sheetId": sheet.id,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": 30,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "destination": {
                    "sheetId": sheet,
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": 30,
                    "startColumnIndex": 1,
                    "endColumnIndex": 2
                },
                "pasteType": "PASTE_FORMAT"
            }
        },
        
        }
    ]
}
res = sheet.batch_update(body)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - GSPREAD - Copy text and format from one google sheet to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042868/python-gspread-copy-text-and-format-from-one-google-sheet-to-another-one)

Comment: I've read this one, tried to apply but this refers to normal pasting, I tried adjusting to format only but it did not work.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue? Because, when I tested `"pasteType": "PASTE_FORMAT"`, the background colors and the number format are copied. So, I thought that I would like to confirm your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is located in the body of the request.

You are supposed to provide the sheet ID of the destination sheet where to copy the format but you provide the `Worksheet` python object instead.

Here:

```json
...
"destination": {
  "sheetId": sheet,
...
```

Or it should be:

```json
...
"destination": {
  "sheetId": sheet.id,
...
```